# OnClick Javascript Ajax Toolkit: Syntax to evaluate Sobject field within if expression

Tags: javascript, custom-button, ajax-toolkit

I have a Javascript button on Case that merely changes the owner when clicked, so far so good.  But I'd like to extend it with a tiny bit of validation that chck to see whether there's a picklist value that is empty (that is, not set) on the Case.  If so, it throws an alert, else updates the case with the new ownerId.  Here's what I've got:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 


var updateRecord = new Array(); 
var myquery = "SELECT Id,txFaultRequestInfo__c,pl_ReasonForAssignment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = '{!Case.Id}' limit 1"; 

result = sforce.connection.query(myquery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

if(records[0]) 
{ 
var update_Case = records[0]; 

if("{update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c}" == '') 
{ 
alert("Picklist value is not set!"); 

} 
else 
{ 
update_Case.OwnerId = "00G20000000jeqC" ;  /* New Value */
//update_Case.OwnerId = "00G20000000jdLD"; /* Older Value */

updateRecord.push(update_Case); 
} 
} 

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecord); 
parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
```

No matter what, it always evaluates the if condition as false and goes to the else condition that updates the OwnerId.  Can you spot the error?

Comment: One thing is this `"{update_Case` should be this `"{!update_Case`. But if that field is editable in the page, then perhaps you should be looking at the input field value not the value when the page was rendered.

Comment: If I add the !,I get an error: "Error:update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c does not exist.  Check spelling".   But it does exist, I can query for it and it is the correct API name.   What I'm doing with the comparison is simply checking whether that field is empty or not.  If there exists a simpler way to to do this i'm all for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update_Case` is a variable at the point where you're referencing it in the `if` condition so you don't need the quotes nor the merge syntax.

A couple of other points, you should always declare JavaScript variables with the `var` keyword and I would suggest using the triple-equals operator in the `if` expression to avoid type coercion:
`if (update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c === '') {`

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}

var updateRecord = new Array();
var myquery = "SELECT Id, txFaultRequestInfo__c, pl_ReasonForAssignment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = '{!Case.Id}' limit 1";

var result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);
var records = result.getArray("records");

if (records[0]) {
    var update_Case = records[0];

    // a little debugging
    alert(update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c);

    if (update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c == '') {
        alert("Picklist value is not set!");

    } else {
        update_Case.OwnerId = "00G20000000jeqC"; /* New Value */
        //update_Case.OwnerId = "00G20000000jdLD"; /* Older Value */

        updateRecord.push(update_Case);
    }
}

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecord);
parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, especially on the triple comparison operator, had forgotten about that.  But I'm still not getting this to work, I have in my test case this picklist (pl_ReasonForAssignment__c) being set to None (ie empty but the comparison operator is not picking up on that and skips straight to the else.

Comment: So what is the value in that field? What do you get when you alert on that field? [null, undefined, empty string, etc] If that isn't providing any data, what do you get when you alert on the entire `update_Case` object?

Comment: I fixed this.  The value when debugged was null, so my comparison for this is is (update_Case.pl_ReasonForAssignment__c == null) .  That works like like I want.  I'll mark your answer as the correct one - Mark.